# proposal documentclass problem

Tags: errors, document-classes

I am having the following minimal example, using the document class proposal.

```
\documentclass{proposal}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

on both my computers I get the following when running pdflatex on it:

Undefined control sequence.

```
\f@ncyolh ->\prop@gen@acronym 
                             \strut 
l.4 \end{document}
```

Comment: It's not a bug: the class needs several things to be set up before starting a document. See the examples in `<TEXTREE>/doc/latex/proposal/examples`

Comment: @egreg Do you want to take any actions?

Comment: @Johannes_B Done

Answer (score 3):

The `proposal` class needs much more than the `\documentclass` line. There are several examples under

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/latex/proposal
```

and you should take one of them as template for building your own.

Comment: another one :-)