# How to use authoryear citation style with proposal document class?

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to use the proposal document class with citation style `authoryear` however for some reason I can't get it to work.

I'm using

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, style=authoryear]{proposal}
```

and it simply ignores the style command. I am open to any suggestions that work,

- Preventing the `biblatex` package from loading within the proposal document class then manually loading it. (I keep getting package clashes and undefined option errors)
- Somehow passing the proper style command to `biblatex`.
- Redefining the current [NamYY] citation style to be (Name, Year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Disclaimer** This answer is only about `proposal`'s loading of `biblatex`. The 'MWE' included below will not be a valid `proposal` document, but a minimal document using the class seems to require quite a bit more than your average document class and I couldn't manage to get it to work easily. See also [proposal documentclass problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270689/35864).

`proposal.cls` loads `biblatex`

```
\RequirePackage[hyperref=auto,style=alphabetic,defernumbers=true,backend=bibtex,backref=true,firstinits=true,maxbibnames=6]{biblatex}[2010/11-19]
```

and there is no class option or other class-provided trick to stop it from doing so.

Unfortunately, the `style` option is one of the few `biblatex` options that must be set at loading time and can not be overwritten with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` or friends later.

The package `scrlfile` provides some nice tools to stop a package from being loaded. As it turns out it is not enough to stop `biblatex` from being loaded, we also need to temporarily disable some `biblatex` commands, because the class uses them directly.

We can then proceed to load `biblatex` ourselves.

Then following MWE demonstrates how that might work.

```
% stop class from loading biblatex
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{biblatex}
% the class uses biblatex commands,
% make them no-ops
\long\def\defbibheading#1#2{}
\def\DeclareBibliographyCategory#1{}
\documentclass[english]{proposal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% make sure biblatex can define the no-ops
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\undef\defbibheading
\undef\DeclareBibliographyCategory

% load biblatex
\UnPreventPackageFromLoading{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

% repeat class code with no-oped commands
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{empty}{}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{featured}
\defbibheading{warnpubs}{\section*{\prop@warnpubs@title}%
  \@ifundefined{prop@gen@pubspages}
 {\@latex@warning{No publication pages specified;
                   use the pubspage key in the proposal environment!}}
  {\prop@warnpubs@message%
 \@for\@I:=\prop@gen@pubspages\do{\par\noindent\csname\@I\endcsname}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you really want to use the `proposal` class, I suggest you get into contact with the maintainer and ask them to make it easier to change the `biblatex` loading options. The solution suggested here is quite a mess.